# How to not print "Decimal" in my output for vectors?

Tags: python, vector

```
from math import sqrt, acos, pi
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

getcontext().prec = 30

class Vector(object):

    CANNOT_NORMALIZE_ZERO_VECTOR_MSG = 'Cannot normalize the zero vector'
    
    def __init__(self, coordinates):
        try:
            if not coordinates:
                raise ValueError
            self.coordinates = tuple([Decimal(x) for x in coordinates])
            self.dimension = len(self.coordinates)

        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError('The coordinates must be nonempty')

        except TypeError:
            raise TypeError('The coordinates must be an iterable')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Vector： {}'.format(self.coordinates)

    def __eq__(self, v):
        return self.coordinates == v.coordinates

    def plus(self,v):
        new_coordinates = [x+y for x,y in zip(self.coordinates, v.coordinates)]
        return Vector(new_coordinates)

    def minus(self,v):
        new_coordinates = [x-y for x,y in zip(self.coordinates, v.coordinates)]
        return Vector(new_coordinates)

    def times_scalar(self,c):
        new_coordinates = [c*x for x in self.coordinates]
        return Vector(new_coordinates)

    def magnitude(self):
        coordinates_squared = [x**2 for x in self.coordinates]
        return Decimal(sqrt(sum(coordinates_squared)))

    def normalized(self):
        try:
            magnitude = self.magnitude()
            return self.times_scalar(Decimal(1.0)/magnitude)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            raise Exception(self.CANNOT_NORMALIZE_ZERO_VECTOR_MSG)


#normalization
v3 = Vector([5.581, -2.136])
v4 = Vector([1.996, 3.108, -4.554])
print(v3.normalized())
print(v4.normalized())
```

The output is:

```
Vector： (Decimal('0.933935214086640295130539147343'), Decimal('-0.357442325262329983594964055642'))
Vector： (Decimal('0.340401295943301353537171045562'), Decimal('0.530043701298487295255023200306'), Decimal('-0.776647044952802835008995686630'))
```

Why is this? How can I get it to print without the word "Decimal"?

Comment: Have you looked at the `Decimal` class to see what facilities it has for formatting?

Comment: You're setting your numbers to be of type `Decimal` (which is distinct from the regular `float` type that has no special text denoting their type when printing). If you don't want it to show the `Decimal`, you either need to format how the `Decimal` is printed, or use `float`s instead of `Decimal`s. But keep in mind that `float`s and `Decimal`s have different properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a string with all the decimals, use the builtin `str` method:

```py
>>> str(decimal.Decimal(2.1))
'2.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625'
```

If you want a specific number of decimals use Python string formatting:

```py
>>> f"{decimal.Decimal(2.1):0.2}" # Use :0.n where n is the number of decimals
'2.1'
```

or with `.format`

```py
>>> "{:0.2}".format(decimal.Decimal(2.1))
'2.1'
```

[Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter)

### **EDIT**

Your `__str__` method would be something like this:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return 'Vector： {}'.format(str(x) for x in self.coordinates)
```

Answer (score 0):

Printing a tuple defaults to displaying the `__repr__()` of the contained objects, which is a technical representation for debugging and usually includes the type.  What you want is the `__str__()` (the "pretty" representation) so you must format them yourself.

Also note that you must initialize `Decimal` with strings or you will capture the floating point inaccuracy you are trying to avoid.

Example (removed unnecessary code not necessary to demonstrate the issue):

```py
from math import sqrt, acos, pi
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

getcontext().prec = 30

class Vector:
    def __init__(self, coordinates):
            self.coordinates = tuple([Decimal(x) for x in coordinates])
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Vector: ({', '.join(str(x) for x in self.coordinates)})"

v1 = Vector([5.581, -2.136])         # Initialized without strings
v2 = Vector([1.996, 3.108, -4.554])

v3 = Vector(['5.581', '-2.136'])
v4 = Vector(['1.996', '3.108', '-4.554'])
print(v1)
print(v2)
print(v3)
print(v4)
```

Output:

```
Vector: (5.58100000000000040500935938325710594654083251953125, -2.13600000000000012079226507921703159809112548828125)
Vector: (1.995999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375, 3.108000000000000095923269327613525092601776123046875, -4.5540000000000002700062395888380706310272216796875)
Vector: (5.581, -2.136)
Vector: (1.996, 3.108, -4.554)
```